Sitecore Multi-Zone Setup: Solr Index not Updating in One Zone during Indexing
Sitecore setup with 4 CD servers configured into two zones:

zone-a: servers 01a and 02a
zone-b: servers 01b and 02b

Each zone has its own Solr Cloud setup:

zone-a points to a Solr cluster with three nodes.
zone-b points to a separate Solr cluster.

Using "OnPublishEndAsync" index strategy for zone-b servers.
Issue: Solr index updates

zone-b Solr index updates properly during publish or index rebuild.
zone-a Solr index updates only during Sitecore publish, but not
during indexing.

Verified Solr connection strings and configurations for both zones.
Solr clusters are up and running without issues.
Seeking help:
Has anyone encountered a similar issue with multi-zone Sitecore setups? Any insights or suggestions on troubleshooting and resolving the issue would be greatly appreciated. Additional information about the setup or configuration can be provided if needed.

I dont use SolrCloud, but I imagine its similar setup to local setup. How many Sitecore CM instances do you have? Only one instance should be configured to have the 'indexing' role. That instance should point to a master SOLR instance, from which multiple slave SOLR instances should replicate from. Do you have a master SOLR in each cluster? or do the replicate across zones?

What is the indexing strategy for zone-a? Which specific configurations did you verify?
